# Reverse the digits in a string using Perl

Tags: perl, reverse

I have a string of digits. Say for eg: "234615". Now I should flip the digits between the first lowest digit and second lowest digit.

From the above string, first lowest digit is "1" and second lowest digit is "2". The digits between the first lowest digit and 
second lowest digit are "346". Now, this "346" should be written as "643".

Hope I stated the problem clearly.

Here is the code I tried,

```
my $a = "234615";
my @g = split("", $a);
@g = sort(@g);
my $first  = $g[0];
my $second = $g[1];
print "$first \t $second\n\n";

for(my $i = 0; $i < $#g; $i++) {

    if ($g[$i] == $first) {

    }

    if ($g[$i] == $second) {

    }
}
```

I above code can find first lowest digit and second lowest digit. But I am not sure about the reverse part.

Can some one help me in this?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write few details. The first lowest digit should come first and followed by the reverse digits till second lowest digit. The expected output for the above problem is "164325"

Comment: What if you have duplicate lowest digits, such as `11345272`?

Comment: There won't be any duplicates in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
my $a = "234615";
my @g=split("",$a);
@g=sort(@g);
my $first=$g[0]; my $second=$g[1];

my @ar = split(/($first|$second)/,$a);

$ar[2] = reverse($ar[2]);

print join("",@ar)."\n\n";
```

returns 264315 too

edit after I am's update:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $a = "234615";
my @g=split("",$a);
@g=sort(@g);
my $first=$g[0]; my $second=$g[1];

my @ar = split(/($first|$second)/,$a);
my @result;
push(@result,
    $ar[0],
    $ar[1].$ar[2].$ar[3],
    $ar[4]);
$result[1] = reverse($result[1]);

print join("",@result)."\n\n";
```

returns 164325

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write few details. The first lowest digit should come first and followed by the reverse digits till second lowest digit. The expected output for the above problem is "164325"

Comment: Hi niko, I did not understand this line of code my @ar = split(/($first|$second)/,$a);. I know about split command. But, I did not understand your split line of code. Could you explain me?

Comment: Hi I am. Usually split splits at each match. That means from a string that matches twice, you expect a list of 3 outputs. BUT if there is a group in the regex - something in () - than these delimiters are added to the list. Thus, matching a string twice delivers a list of 5. First part, first match, second part, second match, third part. I am not good in explaining, I hope it helps, though :/

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you could do something like this:

```
perl -lwe '$_ = 234615; 
           @a = /\pN/g; 
           my ($n1,$n2) = (sort @a)[0,1]; 
           s/$n2.*?$n1/reverse $&/e; 
           print;'
```

Which produces the output `164325`. The full code for this oneliner is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$_ = shift;                           # first arg is the number
my @digits = /\pN/g;                  # extract digits
my($n1, $n2) = (sort @digits)[0, 1];  # take the two lowest
s/$n2.*?$n1/reverse $&/e;            # reverse digits using /e
print;
```

As you can see, it depends on `$n1` and `$n2` appearing in the specified order, e.g. 2 ... 1. This can of course be reversed, but is hardcoded. If you need it to be flexible, e.g. either 1 ... 2 OR 2 ... 1, it becomes more complicated.

You could do something like this:

```
if (/$n2.*?$n1/ {                # if $n2 appears first
    s/$n2.*?$n1/reverse $&/e;
else {                          
    s/$n1.*?$n2/reverse $&/e;
}
```

The benefit of using a regex instead of a split to extract the numbers is that you do not risk having any non-digits in your input. The reverse procedure is done by matching the entire string `23461` and reversing it, using the `reverse()` function inside an evaluation inside the substitution (`/e` option). The sort is the default sort, which will work when dealing with single digits.

Answer (score 1):

The program below will do what you need, as long as the digits in the string never occur more than once. If either of the lowest values occur multiple times then you need to define which of them delmits the substring that must be reversed.

It starts by putting a sorted list of the digits into `@sorted`, much as your own program does. Then it takes the first two of those digits, uses `map` with `index` to convert them into a pair of offsets into the string, sorts them so that the first is the earliest is first, and then does the replacement.

The `for` is there to avoid the need to call `substr` twice. It aliases the required substring with `$_` and just reverses it in-place.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '234615';

my @sorted = sort split //, $str;
my @indices = sort { $a <=> $b } map { index $str, $_ } @sorted[0,1];

for (substr $str, $indices[0] + 1, $indices[1] - $indices[0] - 1) {
  $_ = reverse $_;
}

print $str;
```

**output**

```
264315
```

Comment: In that solution, weird inputs like 345111222345 or just 112345 will cause weird outputs... But I don't know for sure what the output SHOULD be.

Comment: That is why I have written the proviso that the digits must be unique. Only the OP knows what he wants in that case and it is pointless writing code on the basis of a speculation.

Comment: Ooops, didn't recognize that proviso. Sorry!

Answer (score -1):

```
  print "Enter the String to be reversed : ";
  $name = <STDIN>;
  chomp $name;
  @array = split(undef,$name);
  $len = length($name);
  for($i=$len; $i>=0;  $i--)
     {
        print "@array[$i]";
      }
```

Comment: The question asked for ways to reverse 2 digits in the string, not reverse the entire string.